# Checking keyboardModifiers() in QComboBox selection

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

In Python PyQt5 I made a method which checks if when button/combobox is pressed with Ctrl it should add a comment:

```
    def add_comment(self):
        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            comment, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Comment', 'Add comment:')
        else:
            comment = ''
        return comment
```

Function is called on start of button/selection change.

For button:

```
self.button = QPushButton()
self.button.clicked.connect(partial(self.button_pressed, ...))

def button_pressed(self, ...):
    comment = self.add_comment()
```

For combobox:

```
self.combobox = QComboBox()
box.currentTextChanged.connect(partial(self.selection_change, ...))

def selection_change(self, ...):
    comment = self.add_comment()
```

And now, that code is working for button clicking but not for choosing from combobox, any ideas why?

For combobox it is going to `selection_change` as expected, but `QApplication.keyboardModifiers() != Qt.ControlModifier`

Strange behavior I noticed is that there is one way to add comment to combobox with that code - when I am on the combobox list and by keys I choose new item and then ctrl + enter. For any other situation involving mouse click it isn't working.

Comment: Have you looked at the other signals of QComboBox, like [`activated`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#activated)?

Comment: Checked for activated, same thing happens

Comment: I just noticed that you're using `keyboardModifiers()`, which is almost only valid for [processed] key events (see [the doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#keyboardModifiers)). You should use [`queryKeyboardModifiers()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#queryKeyboardModifiers) instead: "Unlike keyboardModifiers, this method returns the actual keys held on the input device at the time of calling the method."

Comment: Great, now it's working! Thank you